# IE 8 giving issues with Zurb Foundation

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, zurb-foundation

[image]

I am using Zurb Foundation and it works great for almost all the browser however it breaks for IE8 and looks like the picture.

How can I go about fixing it??

**Update with code**

```
.row.above-header.round
        .three.columns.header_image
            = link_to logo, root_url

        .three.columns
            -if current_user.blank?
                =link_to "Sign Up",signup_path, :class=> "signupButtonForModal small radius nice green button"
                =link_to "Login",signin_path, :class=> "signinButtonForModal small radius nice blue button"

        .three.columns
            =form_tag "/search", :method =>"get" do
                =text_field_tag :query,params[:query], :placeholder => "search", :class =>"search round"
                =image_submit_tag("search.png")

        .four.columns.links-header
            %ul(class="block-grid") 
                %li=link_to "About |", about_path, :class => "nice foot"        
                %li=link_to "Contact |", contact_path, :class => "nice foot"
                %li=link_to "Blog |", blogs_path, :class => "nice foot"
                %li=link_to "Program Providers", program_providers_path, :class => "nice foot"
                - unless current_user.blank?
                    %li=link_to "| Logout", signout_path, :class => "nice foot"
```

Comment: updated the question with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to the latest version of Zurb Foundation solved the issue.